# slack の OAuth でユーザが自作アプリのログイン認証時に「インストールする権限がありません」のエラーとなる

Tags: node.js, api, oauth, slack

以下のコードを参考に、Nuxtで作成した自作アプリにslack の OAuthでの
ログイン機能の実装を行ってみました。
https://github.com/odanado/nuxtjs-slack-oauth-example

slack の管理者である私はアプリのログインに成功するのですが、
slack のチャネル、ワークスペースに参加しているメンバーは
以下のエラーメッセージが表示され、自作アプリにログインすることが出来ません。

> 【slackのワークスペース名】 へ 【開発中の自作アプリ名】をインストールする権限がありません
> このワークスペースでこのアプリをインストールする適切な権限がありません。詳細やアプリのインストール依頼についてはアプリ管理者に問い合わせてください。

slack のOAuthで失敗するユーザタイプは、マルチチャネルユーザ、ゲストで失敗することを確認しました。

slack の管理画面からOAuthのためのUser Token Scopes の設定、
及び、アプリのソースコードに記載するスコープ
（nuxtjs-slack-oauth-example/utils/slack.js 内のスコープ設定）は、
identify の場合と users:read
を試してみましたが、どちらも失敗しました。

以下に関しても、意味があるのかどうかわかりませんが試してみました。
・slack の管理画面の「App Management Settings」で「Require App Approval」をONにし、
自作アプリをApproveする。

・slack の管理画面の「App Management Settings」で「Sign in with Slack Settings」をON/OFFで動作確認。

slack のプランはPRO というものです。
なぜマルチチャネルユーザ、ゲストでOAuth 認証が出来ないのでしょうか。
「インストールする権限がありません」、「このワークスペースでこのアプリをインストールする適切な権限がありません。」はどうすれば解決できるでしょうか。

もしもお分かりの方がいたらご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これはアプリの問題ではなく、ワークスペース側の設定の問題です。ワークスペースの設定画面を見ていただければ、管理者がインストールを承認した場合のみインストールが可能な設定となっているはずです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうござます。

ワークスペース側の設定の問題ですね。

それらしい設定で、
slack app directoryに
「アプリの管理設定」-> 「アプリの承認が必要」
というものをONにしていたので、オフにしてみました。

オフの場合の動作説明は以下の通りとなっており、これで動くかと思ったのですが、まだ動かず、苦戦しております。

「現在制限はオフになっていますので、メンバーなら誰でも、好きなアプリを自由にインストールまたはアンインストールできます。事前に承認されたアプリのみインストール可能としたり、不要なアンインストールを防いだりする場合には、この設定をオンにします。」

もしもどなたかお分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたら、
引き続きご教授いただければ幸いです。

なお、同じ設定画面で以下の2項目はオフにしています。
・Slack App ディレクトリのアプリのみを許可する
・マルチチャンネルゲストは、デフォルトのスラッシュコマンドとショートカットのみ使うことができます

Comment: ああ、すみません。ゲストと書いてありましたね。残念ながらゲストはアプリをインストールすることができません。詳細はこちらをご覧ください。 https://slack.com/intl/ja-jp/help/articles/202518103

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございました！理解しました。

Asanaというサービスをslack と連携させて使用しており、AsanaとSlackのユーザの紐付けが出来ているので、自社アプリについてはSlack でOAuth で各ユーザをログインさせて、Slackと連携させようと考えていました。

思い出してみたらAsanaへの招待はメールアドレスで行っていたので、自作アプリのユーザとSlackユーザの連携を行う場合は、Slackユーザ一覧をAPIで取得して、自作アプリのユーザのメードアドレスと手動でアプリ側で紐付ける、などの実装が必要になるのでしょうね。

お教え頂きありがとうございました。助かりました。

Comment: 最終的に、OAuth でログインさせたいユーザをFull Member にして、Slack api 画面の自作アプリの画面のCollaborators にそのユーザを加える、で無事自作アプリにログインし、slackのユーザ情報などを取得することが出来るようになりました。